# Django: Randomizing queryset with pagination in class based view

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm currently using the built-in Django pagination in a listview to display a queryset of users, which works fine.  Now, I would like to randomize the output, but if I pull the queryset in a list and shuffle the objects, the entire lists of users become shuffled as I travel to the different pages.

```
class ExampleListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        output = list(UserProfile.objects.all())
        random.shuffle(output)
        return output
```

Comment: what is the scope in which pages shuffle should be unchanged, user session or whole server run session?

Comment: whole server run session.  I want the output of the users to be paginated by 10 and be able to randomize the list order within each page.

Comment: if I understand You correctly: `[1,3,5,2,4,6,8,7,10,9], [11, 13,12,15,14,16,18,19,20,17], ...` am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I can propose You to override `paginator_class` with custom `Paginator` class

```
class ExampleListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    paginator_class = ShuffledPaginator
    ...
```

For example paginator can be following

```
class ShuffledPaginator(Paginator):
    def page(self, number):
        page = super(ShuffledPaginator, self).page(number)
        random.shuffle(page.object_list)
        return page
```

Comment: Good example. Please update `random.shuffle(page.object_list)` to `random.shuffle(page)`